# Unable to modify protected control on design on inherited user control

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, splitcontainer

I have two `UserControl`, one inherited from the other.

This controls have two `DataGridView`, contained in a `SplitContainer`. In the "base" user control, I defined access modifier for both `DataGrid` and the `SplitContainer` to protected.

In the design mode in the inherited user control, I can modify the `SplitContainer`. It should then be also possible to modify both `DataGrid`, since they are also defined as protected. However, I can't. They are locked and I can't change any property of them.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Once you talk about a parent/child relation, on the other hand, you talk about inheritance, one control inherits from the other. That's a little confusing. Do they inherit, or do they contain each other ? Both is hardly possible or intended.

Comment: Inherited. I create one user control with the splitContainer and the two DataGrid. Then I define another control being an inherited class of the first one, to add some extra functionality that I don't want in the base control

Comment: OK, but than you result in one control only. There are no two controls. Designer cannot modify base controls, this is by design of Designer. You can modifiy it in your manual programming, if you like. But the better approach is, if you want two controls with something in common, put the common part into a third control. Parent/Child relation is the proposed way to do this, not inheritance.